# load html content with links from database

Tags: html, asp.net, browser

I have a problem with links in asp.net webform app. I create website with page post.aspx that contain asp:label. To this label I load html content from database using this code:

```
lbl_Text.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(_Item.Text) 'item is my custom object
```

Everything works OK, but I have problem with links, mainly with external websites. In example, this blog is on "web1.com" and link is to "web2.com".

In database I store this HTML content in database:

```
You can <a href=”http://web2.com”>download</a> this
```

This is also in page source loaded into browser. Then is this link changed to:

```
http://web1.com/"http://web2.com"
```

Where can be the problem if I use standard project that generate visual studio 2013? Is it in loaded JavaScript? Where I can change this.

Comment: Are these the actual quotes you use `”http://web2.com”` because they look curly to me

Comment: No these are samples